# Google Chrome - passing a variable to an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently I'm trying to pass an array from the context_script into my popup.html on a button click from the extension. However there have been complications which I can't seem to solve on my own, almost every single one of the implementation methods in SO and other sites don't seem to work out.

All I really need is to simply pass a single list from the context, into the JavaScript page that handles the extensions HTML interface.

**background.js**

```
"use strict";
function Master() {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    this.time = 0;

    this.http_usage = this.get_http();
    this.https_usage = this.get_https();
    this.todays_usage = this.get_today_sites();

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponce) {
        sendResponce("Hello world");
    });

    this.init();
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Statistics",
  "description": "Saves time and visitation data.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "background"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "config.js",
        "firebase.js",
        "background.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "styles.css"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Statistics",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**popup.js**

```
function get_data(){
    let data = []
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data:"giblist"}, function (responce) {
    console.log(responce);
    ...
});

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log("Loaded page");
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    document.getElementById("showStatistics").addEventListener("click", get_data);
});
```

Comment: The question doesn't contain any [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) code.

Comment: @wOxxOm After many hours of frustration, I deleted the codesnippets I've done so far because none of them made really any sense in the context at the moment.

Comment: Messaging per se is simple. Not including the relevant code makes it impossible to provide a helpful answer. I can only guess what went wrong. A common pitfall is trying to send a non-JSON-ifiable object of class instances or DOM elements. Maybe you should start with an extremely simple extension that does only messaging and console.log to make sure you know the basics (see also [sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples)).

Comment: @wOxxOm Went with what is my understanging of sending messages from what was available online. Could you throw a look on it?

Comment: The code is correct. Debug it: set breakpoints in the callbacks of onMessage and sendMessage, click the button and see what happens.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. The code is not complete. We would need at least a *popup.html*, where `Master()` is called, `config` defined, what version of Firebase, etc.